# D-Link AC3200 router does not recognize USB printer

Tags: router, printer

I'm attempting to connect a D-Link AC3200 (dir-890l) to an HP 2540 printer with a USB cable. Currently the router does not recognize the printer at all.
The router is not connected to the internet, but functions otherwise.

Comment: The USB port is for storage or file sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [manual](ftp://ftp2.dlink.com/PRODUCTS/DIR-890L/REVA/DIR-890L_REVA_MANUAL_1.00_EN_US.PDF) the usb port can be used as a "printserver". However, the DJ2540 is a host-based printer, which relies on the PC to convert the page into dots on the page. Such a printer is always hard to network. The best way is to connect it to a PC and share it.

If you want to use a printserver you need to find one that specifically supports your printer as that is the only way it will work. The AC3200 does not appear to offer support for the DJ2540, as the D-Link printer compatibility lists I could find does not list wither your printer or your router.

Comment: Got it to work, seems there's an additional piece of software required on each computer called "Shareport". The router does not recognize the printer, but the computer can recognize it through the router.